# Using regex, best way to get all punctuations from a line in Python?

Tags: python, regex

i tried something like this but it's a bit long:

```
punct_tab=[]
for line in f:
    tab=line.split()
    for word in tab:
        if re.search(r",",word)!=0:
               punct_tab.append(',')
        if re.search(r".",word)!=0:
               punct_tab.append('.')


         .... ETC
```

Do you have a better idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex for this?

Comment: Never use `!=/==` for checking the validation. Just use `if re.search(r",",word)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`string.punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.punctuation):

```
>>> import string
>>> 
>>> line = "Hello, world!"
>>> 
>>> punctuation = set(string.punctuation)
>>> print([c for c in line if c in punctuation])
[',', '!']
```

Comment: Or, for your final part: `print(punctuation.intersection(line))`

Comment: @Robᵩ good catch, in case the order does not matter here..thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If using regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = 'string. With; Punctuation?'
>>> re.findall('[^\w\s]', line)
['.', ';', '?']
```